# Create dynamic Bootstrap 4 Accordion with data from Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, accordion

I'm attempting to create a Bootstrap 4 Accordion. I'm using an Ajax call to get the data, and the data is correctly logging to console. I'd like to do a ForEach loop, and append a new card to the Accordion for every Album returned in the JSONP dataset.

The issue I'm running into: the HTML loads first, then I receive the data, and then nothing happens after that, accordion does not render.

How do I load the accordion after all the data is ready?

Relevant HTML (artist ID is an integer):

```
<div id="discogAccordion">                        

  <script type="text/javascript">
      let url = 'https://api.deezer.com/artist/' + {{ artist_id }} +'/albums?output=jsonp';
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/tracklist.js" %}">
  </script>
</div>
```

Relevant JS (js/tracklist.js):

```
$(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('all data: ', data);
        albumAccordion(data);
    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
        console.log('x', x);
        console.log('y', y);
        console.log('z', z);
    }
});
});

let albumAccordion = function (data) {
    data.data.forEach(function (item, index) {
    console.log(item, index);
    return $('.discogAccordion').append(

        '<div class="card">'+
            '<div class="card-header" id="heading'+ index +'">'+
                '<h5 class="mb-0">'+
                    '<button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse'+ index +'"'+
                            ' aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse'+ index +'">'+
                        'enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry '+
                    '</button>'+
                '</h5>'+
            '</div>'+

            '<div id="collapse'+ index +'" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading'+ index +'" data-parent="#discogAccordion">'+
                '<div class="card-body">'+
                    'Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'
    );
});
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the function selects the class name `.discogAccordion`, but your accordion container has `<div id="discogAccordion">`. So, the correct way to select the  accordion container is `$('#discogAccordion')`...

[Demo on Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/wr9gjn3Xxg)

```
let albumAccordion = function (data) {
    data.data.forEach(function (item, index) {
    console.log(item, index);
    $('#discogAccordion').append(
        '<div class="card">'+
            '<div class="card-header" id="heading'+ index +'">'+
                '<h5 class="mb-0">'+
                    '<button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse'+ index +'"'+
                            ' aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse'+ index +'">'+
                        item.title+
                    '</button>'+
                '</h5>'+
            '</div>'+

            '<div id="collapse'+ index +'" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading'+ index +'" data-parent="#discogAccordion">'+
                '<div class="card-body">'+
                    'Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'
    );
});
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/wr9gjn3Xxg

Alternatively, you could give the accordion the `<div id="discogAccordion" class="discogAccordion">` class name, and then the original function that selects `$('.discogAccordion')` would work.

Comment: It's working! Absolutely brilliant. It seems so obvious now- but I spent a few hours trying to figure that out. Thank you so much for your help.